# ResCarousel Active item how to

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I want to change the active starting item to 3 instead of 1s. In short instead of number 1s is active. I want to change it to number 3 staring item or anything if I add active on a class. How Can I achieve that stuff. I'm all over the internet but nothing happens.

Please see below sample of my code html and javascript.

```js
//Small carosel code set here
$(document).ready(function() { ResCarouselOnInit(); });

$(window).resize(function() {
    var r = new Date();
    setTimeout(function() {
        ResCarouselResize(r);
    }, 200);
});




function ResCarouselOnInit() {
    ResCarouselSize();
    $(document).on('click', '.leftRs, .rightRs', function() {
        ResCarousel(this);
    });
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".ResHover", function() {
        $(this).addClass("ResHovered");
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".ResHover", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ResHovered");
    });
}

// Rescarousel Auto Slide
function ResCarouselSlide(e) {
    var thiss = $(e).find(".rightRs");
    var dataInterval = $(e).attr('data-interval');
    !isNaN(dataInterval) && $(e).addClass("ResHover") && setInterval(function() {
        !(thiss.parent().hasClass("ResHovered")) && ResCarousel(thiss);
    }, +(dataInterval));
}

function ResCarouselResize() {
    function myfunction() {
        console.log("resize Works");
        //var r = $('body').width();
        $('.resCarousel').each(function() {
            var divValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
            var itemWidth = $(this).find('.item').width();
            $(this).find(".resCarousel-inner").scrollLeft(divValue * itemWidth);
            //var itemsSplit = $(this).attr("data-items").split(',');
            //var it = r >= 1200 ? itemsSplit[3] : r >= 992 ? itemsSplit[2] : r >= 768 ? itemsSplit[1] : itemsSplit[0];
            //$(this).attr("data-itm", it);
        });
    }
    //var ResTimeout = setTimeout(function() { myfunction() }, 3000);
    //clearTimeout(ResTimeout);
    //ResTimeout = setTimeout(function() { myfunction() }, 3000);
    //console.log(ResTimeout);
    myfunction();
}

//this function define the size of the items
function ResCarouselSize() {
    var t0 = performance.now();

    //    styleCollector0 = styleCollector1 = styleCollector2 = styleCollector3 = "";
    $('.resCarousel').each(function(index) {
        var itemsSplit = $(this).attr("data-items").split('-');
        $(this).addClass("ResSlid" + index);

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                var styleCollector0 = ".ResSlid" + index + " .item {width: " + 100 / itemsSplit[i] + "%}";
            } else if (i == 1) {
                var styleCollector1 = ".ResSlid" + index + " .item {width: " + 100 / itemsSplit[i] + "%}";
            } else if (i == 2) {
                var styleCollector2 = ".ResSlid" + index + " .item {width: " + 100 / itemsSplit[i] + "%}";
            } else if (i == 3) {
                var styleCollector3 = ".ResSlid" + index + " .item {width: " + 100 / itemsSplit[i] + "%}";
            }
        }

        $(this).attr("data-value", "0");
        //var r = $('body').width();
        //var it = r >= 1200 ? itemsSplit[3] : r >= 992 ? itemsSplit[2] : r >= 768 ? itemsSplit[1] : itemsSplit[0];
        //$(this).attr("data-itm", it);

        var styleCollector = "@media (max-width:767px){" + styleCollector0 + "}" +
            "@media (min-width:768px){" + styleCollector1 + "}" +
            "@media (min-width:992px){" + styleCollector2 + "}" +
            "@media (min-width:1200px){" + styleCollector3 + "}";
        //$(this).append("<div class=\"ResStyleManager\"></div>")
        $(this).find("style").remove();
        $(this).append("<style>" + styleCollector + "</style>");
        ResCarouselSlide(this);

    });
    //console.log(styleCollector);
    //$("body").append("<div class=\"ResStyleManager\"></div>")
    //$('.ResStyleManager').html(null).append("<style>" + styleCollector + "</style>");
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to Size');
}

//this function used to move the items
function ResCarousel(Btn) {
    //var t0 = performance.now();
    var parent = $(Btn).parent(),
        slide = +parent.attr("data-slide"),
        itemsDiv = parent.find('.resCarousel-inner'),
        //divValueq = +parent.attr('data-value'),
        itemSpeed = +parent.attr("data-speed"),
        itemLoad = +parent.attr("data-load"),
        //animi = parent.attr("data-animator"),
        translateXval = '',
        currentSlide = "",
        itemLenght = itemsDiv.find(".item").length,
        itemWidth = itemsDiv.find('.item').outerWidth(),
        dataItm = +Math.round(itemsDiv.outerWidth() / itemWidth),
        cond = $(Btn).hasClass("leftRs"),
        divValue = Math.round(itemsDiv.scrollLeft() / itemWidth);
    //console.log(dataItm + "," + Math.abs(dataItmq));
    //console.log(divValue + "," + divValueq);
    //console.log(cond);
    //console.log(typeof + parent.attr("data-slide"))
    itemSpeed = !isNaN(itemSpeed) ? itemSpeed : 400;
    slide = slide < dataItm ? slide : dataItm;

    if (cond) {
        currentSlide = divValue - slide;
        translateXval = currentSlide * itemWidth;
        var MoveSlide = currentSlide + slide;
        //console.log(itemloop);
        if (divValue == 0) {
            currentSlide = itemLenght - slide;
            translateXval = currentSlide * itemWidth;
            currentSlide = itemLenght - dataItm;
            itemSpeed = 400;
            //console.log(currentSlide + "," + translateXval);
        } else if (slide >= MoveSlide) {
            currentSlide = translateXval = 0;
        }
    } else {
        currentSlide = divValue + slide;
        translateXval = currentSlide * itemWidth;
        var MoveSlide = currentSlide + slide;

        //console.log(itemLenght + "," + (MoveSlide + "," + slide + "," + dataItm));
        //console.log(itemLenght + "," + (MoveSlide - slide + dataItm));
        //console.log((divValue + dataItm) + "," + itemLenght);
        if (divValue + dataItm == itemLenght) {
            currentSlide = translateXval = 0;
            itemSpeed = 400;
        } else if (itemLenght <= (MoveSlide - slide + dataItm)) {
            currentSlide = itemLenght - slide;
            translateXval = currentSlide * itemWidth;
            currentSlide = itemLenght - dataItm;
        }
        // resCarouselAnimator(itemsDiv, currentSlide + 1, currentSlide + slide);
    }
    //console.log(slide + "," + itemWidth);
    parent.attr("data-animator") == "lazy" && resCarouselAnimator(itemsDiv, cond ? 0 : 1, currentSlide + 1, currentSlide + dataItm, itemSpeed, (slide * itemWidth));
    //console.log(itemsDiv.scrollLeft() + "," + translateXval)
    //console.log(itemSpeed);
    if (!isNaN(itemLoad)) {
        itemLoad = itemLoad >= slide ? itemLoad : slide;
        //console.log((itemLenght - itemLoad) <= currentSlide + dataItm);
        //console.log((itemLenght - itemLoad) + " ," + (currentSlide + dataItm) + " ," + (itemLenght - dataItm));
        (itemLenght - itemLoad) <= (currentSlide + dataItm) && ResCarouselLoad1(itemsDiv);
    }
    itemsDiv.animate({ scrollLeft: translateXval }, itemSpeed);
    parent.attr("data-value", currentSlide);

    //var t1 = performance.now();
    //console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate');
}


function ResCarouselLoad1(e) {
    //console.log(e.attr("id"));
    $("#" + e.attr("id")).trigger("ResCarouselLoad");
}

function resCarouselAnimator(parent, direction, start, end, speed, length) {
    //console.log(parent + "," + start + "," + end);
    var val = 5;
    if (direction == 0) {
        for (var i = start - 1; i < end + 1; i++) {
            val = val * 2;
        }
        val = -val;
    }
    //console.log(length);
    //if (direction == 1) {
    //    for (var i = start - 1; i < end + 1; i++) {
    //        length = length / 2
    //        console.log(length);
    //    }
    //    //val = val;
    //}
    //val = direction == 1 ? length : -length;

    for (var i = start - 1; i < end; i++) {
        val = direction == 0 ? val / 2 : val * 2;
        //console.log(val);
        //console.log(parent.find(".item").eq(i).find("h1").text());
        parent.find(".item").eq(i).css("transform", "translateX(" + val + "px)");
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        parent.find(".item").attr("style", "");
    }, speed - 70);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>ResCarousel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 


    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Trirong', serif;
            background: #eee;
        }
        
        .p0 {
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .resCarousel-inner .item {
            /*border: 4px solid #eee;*/
            /*vertical-align: top;*/
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .resCarousel-inner .item .tile div,
        .banner .item div {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 250px;
            text-align: center;
            /*box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);*/
        }
        
        .resCarousel-inner .item h1 {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .banner .item div {
            background: url('demoImg.jpg') center top no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            min-height: 550px;
        }
        
        .item .tile div {
            background: url('demoImg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 200px;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .item div h1 {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
        }

        /*resCarousel Css*/

.outt {
    display: none;
}

.leftRs {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 999px;
}

.rightRs {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 999px;
}

.resCarousel {
    /*float: left;
    overflow: hidden;*/
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.resCarousel-inner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.resCarousel-inner .item {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: initial;
}


/*banner*/

.banner {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}


/*tile css*/

.resCarousel-inner .item .tile {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    margin: 5px;
}


/*animation*/

.resCarousel[data-animator="lazy"] .item {
    transition: .6s ease all;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .leftRs,
    .rightRs {
        /*display: none;*/
    }
    .resCarousel-inner {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
}


/*resCarousel Css End*/
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  
   <!-- test -->
    <!--home-->
    <div class="container p8">
        
        <div class="resCarousel carousel" id="puta" data-type="multi" data-items="2-4-4-4" data-slide="4"  data-interval="false" data-value="8">
            <div class="resCarousel-inner">

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>1s</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>2</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>3</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>4</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>5</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>6</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>7</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>8</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>9</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>10</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>11</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>12</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>13</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="tile">
                        <div>
                            <h1>14</h1>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <button class='btn btn-default leftRs'><</button>
            <button class='btn btn-default rightRs'>></button>
        </div>
    </div>

  
    <hr>
 
   
    <script src="js/resCarousel.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```